# What is a simple, testable, cross platform C++ GUI?

Tags: c++, user-interface, tdd

I am looking to build a very simple GUI for a C++ application. Fancyness, design and advanced features don't matter. What is important however, is that I can write automated tests against it, programmatically checking content of fields and clicking buttons. It also needs to run at least on Linux and Windows, preferably also Mac. Any suggestions?

Edit:Open Source tools are highly preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Sorry I am a bit late in answering.</sub>

Well there are many options in GUI programming. However, since you say you want something simple without flairs and eye-candy, the choice narrows down a little. Here are my suggestions:

### [QT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework))

Pretty awesome. Don't want   to sound like a Nokia (or Trolltech) evangelist, but this framework has it all. Mature API, Good design, Platform independence, Flexibility you name it! However, simplicity? Well... that's not a strong point, in fact, QT is the exact opposite. It tends to be more on the extremely heavy and well-armed side, definitely not simple.

### [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)

Again, pretty cool. Supports less platforms than QT, but has a pretty mature API, works on all the platforms you mentioned, the design is pretty awesome too. Flexibility? Well the new GTK+ 3 is a lot flexible but GTK+ 2 (the current latest supported version for Windows) lacks a bit in this respect. It's simpler than QT however, less eye-candy etc. But it relies on a ton of third-party libraries, which is a bit of a disadvantage for some platforms.

<sub>For a comparison between the above two, see [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441127/gui-development-qt-vs-gtk/9443796#9443796).</sub>

### [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)

Frankly, IMHO this is the toolkit that fits your needs the best. It's simple, platform-independent, very easy to deploy and cross-compile and pretty mature (though it's community is not quite as active as GTK+ and QT). It's OpenGL based, and looks pretty much similar on all platforms (I don't know if this is  a pro or con in this case ). It's got a pretty lenient license, you can statically link the entire library, no dependencies except OpenGL.
Runs on all platforms supported by OpenGL.

---

> I am looking to build a very simple GUI for a C++ application. Fancyness, design and advanced features don't matter. What is important however, is that I can write automated tests against it, programmatically checking content of fields and clicking buttons. It also needs to run at least on Linux and Windows, preferably also Mac.

Overall, from the requirements you mentioned, I think FLTK is ideal for you. Though you should also take a look at the other two if you aren't satisfied.

**Update**:

**Testing Frameworks**:

Unfortunately, I haven't seen any good testing framework for FLTK though. For QT, there is the QTestLib. For GTK there is [dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/).

Comment: FLTK seems nice, I like the ability to statically link the entire lib. But do you know if there is a testing framework available? My main requirement is to be able to do automated end-to-end tests through the GUI, simulating a user clicking a button, verifying contents of labels etc.

Answer (score 3):

Suggest that you use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-sdk/) as mentioned above. It is mature and there are new features getting added. To test apps written in Qt, you have the following options

1. [QtTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html)
2. [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/index.php)

And some more ideas [on QtCentre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10615-Open-source-automated-testing-tool-for-Qt-App)

**Update:** Since there is support for Python and Qt in [pyqt](http://qt-articles.blogspot.in/2010/07/how-to-customize-listview-in-qt-using.html) creating a test-suite using something like [pyunit](http://pyunit.sf.net) will be a good option

I am not aware of the level of support for other libraries, but good contendors are - wxwindows and GTk

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into Qt library? http://www.qt.io/

Answer (score 2):

QT http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You can try fltk it is cross-platform and lightweight. The other choice is qt